# write on xml in windows phone silverlight 7

Tags: xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I would like to ask something about XML files.
I have a silverlight for windows phone app created in Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4. I take from the internet an XML file parsing its values to check if username exists. XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
    <item>
        <username>name1</username>
        <score>0</score>
    </item>
    <item>
        <username>name2</username>
        <score>0</score>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

and call a function (if username does not exists) which is:

```
public void AddUser()//Stream stream)
        {
            string stream = "http://localhost:8080/scores.xml";
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            //add user to xml
            //XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
            using (var SourceStream = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
            {
                //settings.Async = true;
                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(SourceStream);
                writer.WriteStartElement(stream);
                writer.WriteStartElement("channel");
                writer.WriteStartElement("item");
                writer.WriteElementString("username", IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["username"].ToString());
                writer.WriteElementString("score", "0");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();       
            }
        }
```

So, what I want to do is add a new person in this XML file. For example:

```
<item>
<username>name3</username>
<score>0</score>
</item>
```

Furthermore, if I run this code I get an error message that says:

```
"Invalid name character in 'http://localhost:8080/scores.xml'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name"
```

I do not know what to do with this error, and if this is the only error...I am not sure I understand exactly how XML works here, could anyone give me some tips or directions to do this ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in

```
writer.WriteStartElement(stream);
```

The Uri of the feed is not a valid element name, I presume you meant to write

```
writer.WriteStartElement("rss");
```

Also, I find it easier to just use Linq to xml, much easier to manipulate, but that's just my preference.

Comment: I changed the stream to "rss", but nothing happened in my XML file.   My XML file would be stored to a server. Read the file, Edit and store it back to server! Now I am working on it locally using xampp to test it first.. Should I see some changes, by doing "rss"?

Comment: I think that you need to re-think your approach. if I'm not mistaken, you wish to load an xml file from a remote location, add to the xml file and then save the file to the same remote location?

Comment: Yes that's right! I load the xml file to see if the username is already in use. If not, I want to add to the xml file and save the file to the same remore location! thanks !!!

Comment: In which case it can't be as straightforward as what you have. The best way to go about it is to have some sort of web service (eg REST service) on the server, which you can pass a new record to and save it there. You can't modify the content of an HTTP response on the server in this way.